# google-geocoding response has empty types array for result and address_component. expect "premise"

Tags: geocoding, google-geocoding-api

Recently my code received a result that included a single geocode result, but which had an empty "types" array for both the result and the address_component for a building.

After reading the documentation, I would have expected "types[]" to be populated with "premise" or something to that effect.
From the docs:

```
The types[] array indicates the type of the returned result. This array contains a set of one or more tags identifying the type of feature returned in the result.
```

This input comes indirectly from outside sources, so I cannot simply omit the building name or otherwise modify my request easily in this case.

Is this a bug in the API wrt buildings/premises? Or is this somewhat undocumented, but still valid/expected?

the address geocoded was: "Barclay Tower 10 Barclay Street, New York"

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?sensor=false&address=Barclay+Tower+10+Barclay+Street%2C+New+York
```

the response was:

```
{"status": "OK",
 "results": [{..
  "address_components": [
      "address_components": [{
          "long_name": "Barclay Tower",
          "short_name": "Barclay Tower",
          "types": []
        },
        ...
 "formatted_address": "Barclay Tower, 10 Barclay Street, New York, NY 10007, USA",
 "types": []
 }]
}
```